# How to kill/ exit a running kali linux command while python script is running

Tags: linux, keyboard, terminal, python, kali-linux

I'm running a python script that prints out commands on the terminal (kali linux) to ultimately disconnect my own device from my wifi after x amount of minutes/seconds etc. I can get the commands part down but an issue I'm having is stopping the commands that are running and you have to press a hotkey or a certain keyboard shortcut to exit the search or whatever. I tried `keyboard.press()` with `from pynput.keyboard import Key` but that doesn't work. Is there any way to halt the ongoing command so that the code can execute the rest of the remaining code? I'll just post what I have:

```
 import subprocess
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key

command1= "ifconfig"
command3 = "airodump-ng wlan0"
time.sleep(10)
subprocess.call(command1, shell=True)
subprocess.call(command3, shell=True)

keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.press('c')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

this is to terminate an on going sub-process in python

Comment: I tried most of the examples but it only stops it for a split second and then it goes back to running again